# SASS SystemStack Error: stack level too deep

Tags: wordpress, sass

I've been stuck with this error since yesterday. Whenever I use --watch or when manually compiling my scss. I'm currently using it for the custom theme development of a WordPress site. Tried uninstalling/reinstalling SASS but it's not helping. Here's what it returned to me when I used --trace as recommended:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:28: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

My suspicion is that I nest the elements too much. Is there a limit when nesting on SASS? Do you have any other fixes that I can try? I'll really appreciate it. I don't really wanna go back to manually writing my CSS for this project.

Comment: You can nest up to 3/4 levels, which is preferred.

Comment: I'd check through the mixins etc. You may have an infinite loop or something somewhere.

Comment: Thanks stephen! That fixed it. What happened was the function was replaced by something else when I used the  find and replace all function on Sublime. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks again!